# Prove if $E_k=(I\otimes\langle e_k|)U(I\otimes|e_0\rangle)$ then $U=\begin{bmatrix}[E_1]&.&.\\ [E_2]&.&.\\ [E_3]&.&.\\ .&.&.\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation

In my reference, [Page 365, Operator-sum representation, Chapter 8, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), it is given that

[image: mock]

---

> We have a principal system $Q$ and an environment $E$ and $U$ is a unitary operator acting on the combined system $QE$.
> \begin{align}
> \mathcal{E}(\rho)&=tr_E\bigg(U(\rho\otimes|e_0\rangle\langle e_0|)U^\dagger\bigg)\\
> &=\sum_k(I\otimes\langle e_k|)(U(\rho\otimes|e_0\rangle\langle e_0|)U^\dagger)(I\otimes |e_k\rangle)\\
> &=\sum_k\langle e_k|(U(\rho\otimes|e_0\rangle\langle e_0|)U^\dagger)|e_k\rangle\\
> &=\sum_k(I\otimes\langle e_k|)U(I\otimes|e_0\rangle)\rho(I\otimes\langle e_0|)U^\dagger(I\otimes|e_k\rangle)\\
> &=\sum_k\langle e_k|U|e_0\rangle\rho\langle e_0|U^\dagger|e_k\rangle\\
> &=\sum_k E_k \rho E_k^\dagger
> \end{align}
> where $E_k=(I\otimes\langle e_k|)U(I\otimes|e_0\rangle)=\langle e_k|U|e_0\rangle$ is an operator on the state space of the principal system $Q$, $|e_k\rangle$ are the orthonormal basis vectors of the environment, $|e_0\rangle$ be the initial state (some standard state) of the environment.

Please check [Prove that $tr\Big(\sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k\rho\Big)=1$ for all $\rho$ implies $\sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528926/prove-that-tr-big-sum-k-e-k-dagger-e-k-rho-big-1-for-all-rho-implies-s) for the derivation.

In the problem, $E_k=(I\otimes\langle e_k|)U(I\otimes|e_0\rangle)=\langle e_k|U|e_0\rangle$ where $|e_k\rangle$ are some orthonormal basis vectors and $|e_0\rangle$ be some standard state of the environment $E$.

> How do we say that $U$ is represented as the block matrix
> $$
> U=\begin{bmatrix}
> [E_1] & \cdots & \cdots\\
> [E_2] & \cdots & \cdots\\
> [E_3] & \cdots & \cdots\\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> in the basis $|e_k\rangle$ ?

**My observation:**

If we had an operator $W:V\to V$ and $\{|v_i\rangle\}$ constitute a basis of $V$  then it can be shown that $\langle v_i|W|v_j\rangle$ is the $ij^{th}$ term of the operator $W$, i.e.,
$$
W=\begin{bmatrix}\langle v_1|W|v_1\rangle&\langle v_1|W|v_2\rangle&\cdots\\
\langle v_2|W|v_1\rangle&\langle v_2|W|v_2\rangle&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the representation of the operator $W$ in the basis $\{|v_i\rangle\}$. This is clear!

Unlike $\langle v_i|W|v_j\rangle$ which is a number and $|v_j\rangle$ is a vector, the term $E_k=(I\otimes\langle e_k|)U(I\otimes|e_0\rangle)=\langle e_k|U|e_0\rangle$ is an operator acting on the first system (principal system $Q$) and $I\otimes|e_0\rangle=|e_0\rangle,I\otimes|e_k\rangle=|e_k\rangle$ are matrices.

---

[***Cross-posted on qc.SE***](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28290/show-that-e-k-i-otimes-langle-e-kui-otimese-0-rangle-implies-u-beginb)

Comment: related on physics: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/408976/58382

Comment: Please avoid having a mutliline formula in the subject line, as you are doing now. It can break displays that show lists of questions, or just mess up the formatting in the lists of questions.